# C# winform ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box on a C# Winform that I would like to populate with the string name variables from this list, nothing else. Here is the list code.

```
class Animals
{
    public string averageMass { get; set; }
    public string lifeSpan { get; set; }
    public string whereToFind { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string animalImage { get; set; }
}
class Mammals:Animals
{
    public static List<Mammals> MammalList = new List<Mammals>();
    public string hairColour { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Google "cascading dropdownlists winform", you have business logic in your presentation layer, move it to a business logic layer and bind the ComboBoxes using a Binding Control or by setting the controls data sources via a SelectedValue Change event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on Combobox:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Mammals") //You can also do index e.g. comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0
        {
            comboBox2.DataSource = mammalList;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox2.DataSource = reptileList;
        }
    }
```

Or you can also do this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2.DataSource = fncGetSpecies(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private string[] fncGetSpecies(int intIndex)
    {
        //This will return if selected item is 0 which is Mammals or 1 if the selected item is Reptiles.
        return intIndex == 0 ? mammalList : reptileList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `DataSource` of `ListBox2` based on selection from `ListBox1's` within `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler as follow:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBox1.SelectedIndex==0)//Which is Mammals list
        {
            listBox2.DataSource = reptileList;
        }
        else//Which is Reptiles list
        {
            listBox2.DataSource = mammalList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add string items to combobox using following code

```
combobox.Items.Add(stringItem);
```

Comment: An incredibly vague answer.

Comment: @gplumb                 this is a generic question for adding data to combobox. what else would you suggest here ?